# Converting iTextSharp to iText7: How do I re-create iTextSharp's nested PdfDocument objects in iText7?

Tags: vb.net, itext, itext7

I am converting a heavy implementation of iText5 to iText7 in vb.net. What hair I have not lost is now gray, thanks to the complete API rewrite.

So in many cases, the OLD iTextSharp code will do something like this:

- create a PdfTemplate object A
- Do stuff to it (rotate it, draw on it, etc)
- create another PdfTemplate object B
- Add PdfTemplate object A to PdfTemplate object B using AddTemplate
- Do other stuff to PdfTemplate B (add a paragraph or something)
- Create a new PdfTemplate object C
- Add Pdftemplate object B (which contains PdfTemplate object A) to PdfTemplate object C using AddTemplate

... and so on.

Now in iText7 I can create a PdfCanvas object that can be drawn on using many of the same drawing functions as iTextSharp, etc. But a PdfCanvas cannot be added to another PdfCanvas in the same manner as with iTextSharp.

I looked at the tutorials but the solution didn't seem apparent. I know it can be done but I'm not sure how to accomplish the same.

I've tried to use Xobjects but that is somewhat limiting; can I convert a PdfCanvas to a PdfFormXObject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert `PdfCanvas` into `PdfFormXObject`, but you can use `PdfCanvas` to draw on `PdfFormXObject` directly. In fact, `PdfFormXObject` class in `iText 7` is the direct alternative of `PdfTemplate` class in iText 5, it just has different name which is closer to the PDF specification terminology.

Here is an example of how you can create a `PdfFormXObject`, draw something on it via `PdfCanvas`, and then add this object to a page, again with `PdfCanvas`:

```
//Create form XObject and flush to document.
PdfFormXObject form = new PdfFormXObject(new Rectangle(0, 0, 50, 50));
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(form, document);
canvas.rectangle(10, 10, 30, 30);
canvas.fill();
canvas.release();

//Create page1 and add forms to the page.
PdfPage page1 = document.addNewPage();
canvas = new PdfCanvas(page1);
canvas.addXObject(form, 0, 0).addXObject(form, 50, 0).addXObject(form, 0, 50).addXObject(form, 50, 50);
canvas.release();
```

As you can see, `PdfCanvas` is an abstraction that can be used to draw on pages or `PdfFormXObject`, so you would be able to add objects one into another one with `PdfCanvas` easily.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This really helped move things along.